# Where should I start for learning different laplace operations?

Tags: reference-request

1) Laplace transformation in ODE.

2) Laplacian (del squared) of a PDE

3) Laplacian matrix in matrix-tree theorem for calculating spanning trees

And couple of other places I have encountered these things . Are they correlated ? If so then Where should I start the process of learning ? I am thinking starting from [khan academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-equations/laplace-transform). Am I in right direction ?

Answer (score 0):

The first one has nothing to do with the other two, beyond being tied to the name of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre-Simon_Laplace.

The second and third *are* related. The simplest connection is that the Laplacian matrix of a lattice graph is, up to a scale factor, an approximation of the Laplacian at the points of the lattice.

More precisely, suppose $L_{d,n}$ is the Laplacian matrix of a lattice in dimension $d$ with $n$ points in each direction (for a total of $n^d$ points). Then as $n \to \infty$, $\frac{1}{n^d} L_{d,n}$ converges (in a certain weak sense) to the Laplacian on the unit hypercube. This is nothing but the centered difference approximation for the Laplacian in $d$ dimensions.